# Backbone JS: Where does parameter representing model in collection view come from?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am in the process of learning Backbone JS. While I feel like I made great process so far, there is one thing I don't understand.

Take the following collection view:

```
App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(a) {
      var taskView = new App.Views.Task({model: a});
      this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
  }
});
```

There, parameter `a` represents an object that is used to construct a single view. But where does this parameter come from?

Of course I am aware that it comes from the collection passed to this view, but how come it's freely available – where is defined/documented that this parameter is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically asking about how the [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) function in the `underscore` utility library works.

It iterates over each item in the collection and passes it to the callback function. And in this code you are setting each item in the collection as the model for `App.Views.Task` and appending it to the UI element and then returning the element.

`underscore` is a dependency of Backbone, and the documentation of `each` can be found [here](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Comment: So you mean in my code `a` (or whatever name it is given) is available because underscore's `each` function has passed it on?

Comment: `a` is actually an item in your collection. A better name for that parameter could be `task` or `item` or `itemInCollection`. The callback function will get called for every item in the collection. So, yes, the `each` function passes it on to the callback! :)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it! Pretty simple actually!

Answer (score 0):

`each` is a method from Underscore. It accepts a callback -- the anonymous function that currently takes in `a` as its parameter. This parameter can be named anything, really. It represents **the specific element of this array we are iterating through, at each specific iteration**. I usually like to give it the name `elem` or `value` for clarity's sake. A longer version could be something like `TheElementOfThisCollectionWeAreCurrentlyIteratingOver`.

If you were to use a for loop instead, your code would look like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++) {
  var taskView = new App.Views.Task({model: this.collection[i]});
  this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
}
```

Comment: `each` is not an array prototype method in this context. It's an `underscore` utility function.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line again:

```
this.collection.each(function(a) {
```

`each` calls a function against every model in the collection. `a` is defined as the first parameter of the method and will represent a specific model.